# Find Specific Value In Specific lists of tables

Tags: sql

I have a list of tables that start with 'MxGLBudget'  there are over 300 tables  i need to search for a value in a filed called budgetyear that is a guid

Comment: What is the database? You will have to use some dynamic sql that reads through your set of tables (information_schema.tables in sql server), builds dynamic sql, inserts result into a temp table, and finally reports the results.

Comment: Why all those MxGLBudget tables? Can't you have one, common MxGLBudget table?